# Get Windows environment variables passed to new process (not of current process)

Tags: c#, windows

How do I obtain the complete set of environment variables passed to a new process by the start menu, *not* the set of environment variables passed to my process?  Or how do I launch a process with this set of environment variables?  (I technically do not need to access them in my initial process)

These can diverge, for example, if my process is launched and then the user uses the environment variable GUI to modify them.

Use-case: I'm writing a launcher utility that behaves similarly to the start menu, for starting applications.

A proper solution needs to do the following:

- Get both machine and user environment variables
- Merge the PATH variables from machine and user (Do any other variables merge?)
- Get HOMEDRIVE, HOMEPATH, USERNAME, USERPROFILE, and any other variables not provided by `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(System.EnvironmentVariableTarget.User)`
- NOT inherit environment from the current process

Is there a Windows API call to get this full set of environment variables that the Windows start menu passes to launched processes?  Or is there a way to launch a process such that Windows automatically sets its environment variables without my intervention, and *without* inheriting from the current process?

Comment: The Start Menu is part of the `explorer.exe` shell.  I doubt there's an API specifically for Explorer's environment because that would require it to be special-cased within Windows, whereas Explorer is really just another process. Do you have reason to believe Explorer's environment and/or environment handling would be any different than your/another application, or is it just, like you said, to handle the case of variables being changed after a process is launched? See also: [`ProcessStartInfo.Environment`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environment)

Comment: I wonder if [this technique](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190425-00/?p=102443) also sets the environment variables to those of the "pretend parent" process.

Comment: @BACON You can verify the behavior I'm describing by launching a shell from explorer, logging an environment variable, modifying the value of that variable via Windows' "Edit the system environment variables" UI, then repeat the above.  The second shell will receive the new value.  Ditto for non-shell executables, in case you suspect that shells are behaving uniquely.

Comment: When the system or user "Environment" key is updated, all top-level windows should be sent a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` "Environment" message. In response, Explorer calls the private shell32 function `RegenerateUserEnvironment`. A similar function in the public API is [`CreateEnvironmentBlock`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createenvironmentblock). The main difference is that `CreateEnvironmentBlock` depends almost completely on the system and user profile registry hives. Also, `RegenerateUserEnvironment` supports parsing "C:\autoexec.bat" if it exists.

Comment: In addition to "Path", both functions also merge system and user ["LibPath"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-using-directive-cpp?view=vs-2019) (searched for the compiler #using directive) and "Os2LibPath" (a legacy value for the defunct OS/2 subsystem). Notably the linker's "Lib" variable doesn't get merged.

Comment: @eryksun is C:\autoexec.bat common?  It sounds like something that should definitely be deprecated, so I assume I can ignore it.  In that case, `CreateEnvironmentBlock` sounds like the correct approach.

Comment: No, "autoexec.bat" is not common anymore. A batch script does have the benefit of a guaranteed evaluation order when defining variables that depend on other variables. The registry "Environment" keys (system and user) have no guaranteed ordering. This is addressed by enumerating a key in two passes. `REG_SZ` values are loaded first. `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values are loaded second, so they can reliably depend on any `REG_SZ` values in the key.

Comment: Tough luck if you need a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value to depend on another `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, i.e. more than one level of dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code to parse the full set of environment variables into a C# Dictionary.  It uses `CreateEnvironmentBlock` as suggested in the comments.  `CreateEnvironmentBlock` needs a user token for the user whose variables you want to retrieve.  We can get a token for the user that our process is running as via `OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_READ, out primaryToken);`

Getting the environment block is really easy.  More code is spent parsing the environment block into a C# dictionary, and I'm sure it could be much shorter.

Important bits without error checking:

```
IntPtr primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_READ, out primaryToken);
IntPtr lpEnvironment = IntPtr.Zero;
bool resultEnv = CreateEnvironmentBlock(out lpEnvironment, primaryToken, false);
// Do stuff with lpEnvironment here
DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment);
CloseHandle(primaryToken);
```

Full example, ready to compile:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class EnvVarGetter
{
    public static Dictionary<String, String> GetEnvironmentVariables()
    {
        IntPtr primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_READ, out primaryToken);
        if (primaryToken == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return null;
        }

        IntPtr lpEnvironment = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool resultEnv = CreateEnvironmentBlock(out lpEnvironment, primaryToken, false);
        if (resultEnv != true)
        {
            int nError = GetLastError();
        }

        var envVars = new Dictionary<string, string> { };

        IntPtr next = lpEnvironment;
        while (Marshal.ReadByte(next) != 0)
        {
            var str = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(next);
           // skip first character because windows allows env vars to begin with equal sign
            var splitPoint = str.IndexOf('=', 1);
            var envVarName = str.Substring(0, splitPoint);
            var envVarVal = str.Substring(splitPoint + 1);
            envVars.Add(envVarName, envVarVal);
            next = (IntPtr)((Int64)next + (str.Length * 2) + 2);
        }

        DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment);
        CloseHandle(primaryToken);
        return envVars;
    }

    private static uint STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
    private static uint STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000;
    private static uint TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
    private static uint TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
    private static uint TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
    private static uint TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
    private static uint TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
    private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
    private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
    private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
    private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;
    private static uint TOKEN_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY);
    private static uint TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID);


    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetLastError();

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(out IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, bool bInherit);

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool DestroyEnvironmentBlock(IntPtr lpEnvironment);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle,
    UInt32 DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

    public static int Main()
    {
        // Loop indefinitely till user hits escape
        do
        {
            // Get environment variables
            var vars = EnvVarGetter.GetEnvironmentVariables();
            // Log them
            foreach(var pair in vars)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pair);
            }
            while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
            }
        } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

        return 0;
    }
}
```